# How to add and retrieve from array list?

Tags: java

I'm creating a mock banking program and want to use arraylists to keep track of things like first, last name, account balance, etc. then I want to display these values later with print statements. How do I do this?

Comment: A bit too broad for a question acceptable in SO. Perhaps you can narrow down a bit?

Comment: I just want to store account information variables in arraylists and know how to print all accounts after the user is done inputting accounts (using scanner nextinput)

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your "question" lacks many of the explained requirements. Please be much more specific, especially show your own efforts (your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ArrayList<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();

    Account exampleAccount = new Account();
    exampleAccount.setFirstName("John");
    exampleAccount.setLastName("Doe");
    exampleAccount.setBalance(101.13d);

    accounts.add(exampleAccount);

    for(Account account : accounts) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + account.getFirstName() + " " + account.getLastName() + 
                ".  Balance: " + account.getBalance());
    // Or override Account's toString() method and do System.out.println(account.toString()) 
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for thanks

Comment: @JFranks please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?] (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I accepted answer but can't vote